# Is this formula $T(N(T^2))=R(T)\bigcap N(T)$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a prove but I am not sure if my answer is correct

Given any $T：V\rightarrow V$ where $V$ is arbitrary vector space.

- My question：whether is my prove true?

Answer (score 1):

My answer：

Proof：

1. Let $x\in N(T^2)$ then $x\in V \Rightarrow T(x)\in R(T)$. $\because x\in N(T^2) \therefore T\bigl(T(x)\bigr)=T^2(x)=0 \Rightarrow T(x)\in N(T)$. Hence $\forall x\in N(T^2) \Rightarrow T(x)\in R(T)$ and $T(x)\in N(T) \Rightarrow T\bigl(N(T^2)\bigr)\subseteq R(T)\cap N(T)$.
2. Let $x\in R(T)\cap N(T)$ then $\exists y\in V s.t. T(y)=x$ and $T(x)=0. \because 0=T(x)=T\bigl(T(y)\bigr)=T^2(y)\therefore y\in N(T^2) i.e.\exists y\in N(T^2)s.t. x=T(y)\in T\bigl(N(T^2)\bigr)$ Hence $R(T)\cap N(T)\subseteq T\bigl(N(T^2)\bigr)$.
3. By 1 and 2 $T(N(T^2))=R(T)\bigcap N(T)$.

.